# failure in values logical expression as a if argument in a shiny app

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, logical-operators

I am sorry for the confusing title but I really cannot figure a better one. I hope I can express my problem better with the below example codes and my explanation.

I am trying to make a shiny app, and I need to collect basic information of subjects in the beginning, including age, gender, and their subject ID, which is a 5-digits number. I have checked the below codes many times, and it always shows that the conditions about age and gender work well. Besides, since the subject ID is a 5-digits number, I have set the condition as "input$subject_ID > 99999| input$subject_ID < 9999". However, the subject ID condition is not effective. For example, when I entered 12312 which should fulfill the condition, the app does not update the page as it should do.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Best,
J-L

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(id="main",title="test",useShinyjs(),
                navlistPanel(id="main",widths = c(1, 11),
                             
                             tabPanel("Info",
                                      fluidRow(radioButtons("gender",label="Your gender",choiceNames=c("Please choose:       ","Female","Male"), choiceValues=c(2,0,1),selected=2,inline=T)),
                                      fluidRow(textInput( "age", label="Your age")),
                                      fluidRow(textInput( "subject_ID", label="Your subject ID obtained from last part")),
                                      
                                      fluidRow(actionButton( "submit_info", label="Submit, and next page"))
                             ),
                             
                             tabPanel("Video",
                                      fluidRow()
                                      
                             )))
                
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hide(selector = "#main li a[data-value=Video]")
  
  observeEvent(input$submit_info,{
    if (input$gender == 2 | 18 > input$age | input$age > 80 | input$subject_ID > 99999| input$subject_ID < 9999){
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Message",
        "You have not indicated your age, gender or subject ID (correctly). Please make sure you answer these three infomation questions before you continue.",easyClose=T,footer = modalButton("OK")))
    }else{
      show(selector = "#main li a[data-value=Video]");
      updateNavlistPanel(session, "main", "Video");
      hide(selector = "#main li a[data-value=Info]")
    }})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: You should be using `as.numeric(input$age)<18` and `as.numeric(input$subject_ID)<9999`, as they are character values.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `subject_ID` is a character. Hence, when checking `input$subject_ID > 99999` or `input$subject_ID < 9999` the comparison is done according to lexical order, e.g. while `12345 < 9999` is `FALSE`, `"12345" < 9999` is `TRUE` as in a lexical order a string starting with a `"1"` comes before a string starting with `"9"`.

To solve your issue you could convert `input$subject_ID` to a numeric, i.e. `as.numeric(input$subject_ID) < 9999` or instead check the number of characters using e.g. `nchar(input$subject_ID) != 5`

Comment: Thank you! but I am still confused why the condition works for age? "18 > input$age | input$age > 80"

Comment: (: Actually it does not, e.g. if the user inputs an age of 5 then `18 > input$age` is `FALSE` for the same reason as explained in my answer. Hence, it would also be more robust to convert `input$age` to a numeric.